# Is there any example for sauce labs configuration with serenity/appium to run the scripts against mobile native app ?

Tags: appium, saucelabs, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, thucydides

For my project, all the capabilities are given in serenity properties file. Below is the example:

```
appium.platformVersion=8.1.0
appium.platformName=Android
appium.deviceName=emulator-5554
appium.automationName=uiautomator2
appium.app=app/path
serenity.timeout = 100000
serenity.step.delay = 200
serenity.verbose.steps = true
serenity.take.screenshots = FOR_FAILURES
serenity.resized.image.width = 800 
webdriver.wait.for.timeout = 10000
```

I would like to know how sauce labs configuration like `API_KEY`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD` etc.. will fit in the above properties file or if we can set up the configuration in hooks like `@before` method. if there is an example that would be great?

Thanks
Vamc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in [Serenity official github repo](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/tree/master/serenity-appium#running-in-sauce-labs):

`saucelabs.url=http://sauceId:sauceKey@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
saucelabs.access.key=sauceKey
saucelabs.user.id=sauceId`

Comment: Any idea about below error?
`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Sauce could not start your job.`
Serenity.properties
`
webdriver.driver = appium
saucelabs.url=http://<user>:<accesskey>@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
saucelabs.user.id=<user>
saucelabs.access.key=<acceskey>

appium.automationName = uiautomator2
appium.platformName=Android
appium.platformVersion = 8.1
appium.deviceName  = Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus FHD GoogleAPI Emulator
appium.app = ExactCalculator.apk
`